# Media Query causing text to be squished

Tags: html, css

So I'm currently helping out a friend with a website that they will use for a startup company. I am having a problem with the about us section. On a computer it is a picture and then text beside the picture using flexbox. But on a phone the text is supposed to be bellow the picture. BUT, the text is currently filling up half the screen and is so squished it is laying on top of the picture.

I've tried alot of things but I cant figure it out.

I would appreciate some help.

I've tried alot of things but I cant figure it out.

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Anton, we are happy to help but we can't really do so without seeing your code. Suggest you edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look at the [`flex-wrap` property](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flex-wrap).